# How to add LinearLayout within RecyclerView?

Tags: mobile, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

`enter code here`Here is my .xml

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/listgrad">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="PROMOTE YOUR EVENTS"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="408dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="I'M A SPONSOR" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="I'M A ORGANIZER" />
</LinearLayout>





<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewEvents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and I get errors like this

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slofo.eventus/com.example.slofo.eventus.Eventus_homeview}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus.Eventus_homeview.onCreate(Eventus_homeview.java:22)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus.Eventus_homeview.onCreate(Eventus_homeview.java:22) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus:drawable/rectangle_button" (7f06006d) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06006d a=-1 r=0x7f06006d}
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4249)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4156)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4006)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                      at android.view.View.(View.java:4249)
                      at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:963)
                      at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:112)
                      at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:105)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:71)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:67)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus.Eventus_homeview.onCreate(Eventus_homeview.java:22) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

and here is my .java

```
public class Eventus_homeview extends AppCompatActivity{

List<Events> lstEvents;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventus_homeview);

    lstEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve1));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 1","Conference","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve2));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.0","Camp","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve3));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.5","Exhibit","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve4));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 3.0","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve5));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve1));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 1","Conference","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve2));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.0","Camp","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve3));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.5","Exhibit","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve4));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 3.0","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve5));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve1));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 1","Conference","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve2));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.0","Camp","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve3));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 2.5","Exhibit","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve4));
    lstEvents.add(new Events("Paramore Night 3.0","Concert","Paramore Covers",R.drawable.eve5));


    RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewEvents);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstEvents);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

}

can you please help me how to deal with this? I've been stuck with this for an h our already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such long exceptions, always look at the last `Caused by`which will tell you the actual reason of the exception. There, it says:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus:drawable/rectangle_button" (7f06006d) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06006d a=-1 r=0x7f06006d}
```

That means that there's something wrong with your `com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus:drawable/rectangle_button`. In your xml, you are expecting the `rectangle_button` to be a drawable, but clearly it's not a drawable but something else.

Comment: I change my button background into hexacolors but still it will crash, and I get an error in my code here at the eventus_homeview.java

Comment: I can't guess your exception if you don't post the stacktrace :)

Comment: I posted it including my java code. but the error points out at my .java in line 22 which is the part setContentVIew(R.layout.eventus_homeview)

Comment: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)  at com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus.Eventus_homeview.onCreate(Eventus_homeview.java:22)  this error @vatbub

Comment: Again, have a look at the last `Caused by` where it says `Resource "com.example.jevaltamidles.eventus:drawable/rectangle_button" (7f06006d) is not a Drawable`. Clearly, the exception is thrown in Èventus-homeview.java` line 22 but the cause lies in your `rectangle_button`!

Comment: You were right! I changed the background into hexadecimal and it worked. Thank you so much!